# Selenium error: Failed to resolve address for stun.fpapi.io., errorcode: -105

Tags: python, selenium

I'm really new to selenium with python and I'm having this error that I couldn't figure out how to fix.
When I execute the code, the google tab of selenium opens, it redirects to the URL and then it closes again giving me this error.

**Error:**

```
[25076:14364:0912/211302.884:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(127)] Failed to resolve address for stun.fpapi.io., errorcode: -105
```

[Error in the terminal (it get printed 2 times)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQuMP.png)

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = "https://bloxflip.com/"


driver.get(url)


elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), 'Log in')]")
```

[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JCAk.png)